# block diagonal approximation of (SPD) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I am interested in approximating a symmetric matrix in a block diagonal form, i.e. compute just some entries of the matrix located in blocks around the diagonal. Are there any theoretical guarantees about this approximation? I would be interested to approximate the difference in eigenvalues of the two matrices, i.e. the L2 norm of their difference.

My setting is in second order optimization, where we use the hessian of a function in order to minimize it. Since the problem can be very high-dimensional and the hessian very large, practitioners usually compute just a block-diagonal form of the hessian. However, I was not able to find any theory behind that. If it helps, we can also assume that our matrix is **positive definite** (happens when the function that we wish to minimize is strongly convex).

Any literature around this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Is your matrix diagonally dominant? In that case, at least the positive-definiteness should not be spoiled by the approximation, because the approximating matrix just has fewer non-zero off-diagonal elements and hence is still diagonally dominant.

Comment: The Gershgorin Circle Lemma could be helpful in bounding how much the eigenvalues of the full and block-diagonal matrices can differ.